# How do I pass the self paramater with colon?

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
entity={77,function(self) print(self.x+self.y) end, x=2,y=4}

entity[2](entity) -- 6 

entity:[2]() -- error
```

How to pass the `self` variable with `:`colon?

Comment: Your second line `entity[2](entity)` is the right way.  Semicolon syntax is only for identifier-like fields, not for numerical indices.

Comment: `:` is a colon, not a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 0):

You should put the function in a variable that's not a number, for example

```
entity={77, myFunction = function(self) print(self.x+self.y) end, x=2, y=4}
```

Then you can do

```
entity:myFunction()
```

Comment: alright thank you so much sir, so I have to put identifier in the key of the table. That'd be very much appreciated! 

This is my first time asking in stackoverflow, i dont expect to get answer this quick haha